# send multiple emails stored in database

Tags: php, email, mysqli

i need to send multiple emails stored in database

```
$mysqli = $this->connection(); //connect to db
$dati = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed where active='1'");//select emails
while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) { //while to show
            $email = $resulta['email']; //each mail
}
```

the code above is what im using
but i need to send email with mail function outside the while
and if it send correctly return true the function:

this is the function:

```
function feed_mail($id){
$mysqli = $this->connection(); //connect to db
    $dati = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed where active='1'");//select emails
    while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) { //while to show
                $email = $resulta['email']; //each mail
    }
if(mail($email, $asunto, $html,$header)){
return true;
return false;
}
}
```

$email will be each mail stored in the database
$asunto,$html,$header i didnt added the code here

so how i send each email?

Answer (score 0):

```
function feed_mail($id){
    $mysqli = $this->connection(); //connect to db
    $dati = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed where active='1'");//select emails
    while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) { //while to show
        $email = $resulta['email']; //each mail

        if(mail($email, $asunto, $html,$header)){
            continue;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

Please add your `$asunto,$html,$headeras` you didn't mention them in your question.

```
<?php
function feed_mail($id){
$mysqli = $this->connection(); //connect to db
    $dati = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed where active='1'");//select emails
    $emailArr = array();
    while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) { //while to show
                array_push($emailArr,$resulta['email']);
    }
    foreach($emailArr as $emails){
        if(mail($emails, $asunto, $html,$header)){
    return true;
        }else{
    return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch all emails into an array

```
$email = array();
while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) { //while to show
    $email[] = $resulta['email']; //each mail
}
```

And then send them all on one email (or at least more in one email) attaching them as CC in the headers. Read this [article](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Send-email-with-CC-and-BCC-in-php/68445).

Comment: read the article and you will now it. Adding header like $headers .= "CC: test@test.com, test2@test.com,..\r\n";